# PowerShell script to list files from sftp server folder

Tags: powershell, sftp

I am trying to get list of files from an SFTP folder using the following PowerShell script:

```
$files = Get-SftpChildItem -Host mysftpserver -Port 22 -Username myusername -Password mypassword -RemoteLocation "/MySFTPFolder/outbound/"
ForEach ($f in $files)
{
    "test" | Out-File $ConfigFile -Append
}
```

For some reason I am not able to read the 2 files that are in the remote outbound folder. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: That doesn't look like valid syntax for the `Get-SftpChildItem` cmdlet. Have you run `Get-Help Get-SftpChildItem` yet to see the syntax for that cmdlet? Looks like you need to establish a connection, and then pass that connection to the cmdlet.

Comment: I found the cmdlet online and tested it but not working.  I tried to run the Get-Help but got this: Get-Help : Get-Help could not find Get-SftpChildItem in a help file in this session. To download updated help topics    type: "Update-Help". To get help online, search for the help topic in the TechNet library at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=107116.
At line:1 char:1
+

Comment: Get-Help Get-SftpChildItem
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Get-Help], HelpNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HelpNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand

Comment: Here's where you can find help on that cmdlet, including syntax: https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH/blob/master/docs/Get-SFTPChildItem.md

Answer (score 1):

You may be running an old version of the Posh-SSH module, since your syntax looks very different than mine, and the fact that you don't have help files installed. You should install the latest version with:

```
Find-Module Posh-SSH | Install-Module
```

Then you can create a SFTP session, and use that session to list the child items as you desire:

```
$userName = 'MyUserName'
$secStringPassword = 'MyPassword' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Creds = [pscredential]$credObject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($userName, $secStringPassword)
$session = New-SFTPSession -computername mysftpserver -Credential $Creds
$files= Get-SFTPChildItem -SFTPSession $session -Path "/MySFTPFolder/outbound/"
ForEach ($f in $files)
{
    "test" | Out-File $ConfigFile -Append
}
```

Comment: let me try to update POSH-SSH module and try that.